# Would it possible to upload two different apps to Apple Store and Play Store with highly similar codebase?

Tags: android, ios, google-play

We are building mobile applications with mainly similar codebase, with some "functions" which are not available in all of our apps, so for example 
- "A app": navigaton function is allowed
- "B app": navigation function is not allowed (for example because country law limitations).

Isit  possible to upload it seperately (two different apps with different bundle id/package name) to the Apple Store and Play Store? Won't we get rejection because of the similar codebase?

Thank you!

Comment: I will rather say you can give it a try uploading both seprately, maximum they will gonna reject the apps.

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem. You can use the same code base and create 2 separate apps with different package name to upload to play store. The important thing is your package names should be different for play store to treat it as separate apps.

Comment: Google Play, probably fine. App Store, probably not. The app store review guidelines explicitly stated that you should not upload two versions of the same app (in your case, with or without navigation) as two separate apps. You should combine them into one app that detects the user's country and turns on/off navigation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On the Google Play Store it will not be a problem.

On the Apple App Store it you might get a reject, although I seriously doubt it. As long as you have good intentions there is nothing wrong with an App Store reject and it is not something you should be afraid of. Many legitimite apps gets rejected and after further explanation or small corrections they will be approved.

If your reason is as ligitimite as abiding to local law there absolutely should be no problem.

Both in Google Play Store and Apple App Store you can limit the availability of an app to certain countries. So in this case you would ensure "A app" is available in all countries except the countries where it is illegal. Similarly "B app" should only be available the countries where it is necessary to limit the functionality because of local laws.

The result would be that no country has both apps available. This is also the least confusing for users.